# arrays in SAS with more columns

Tags: sas

I have a dataset

```
Data have;
input A B C; 
cards; 
1 . .
. . 1
1 1 .
run;
```

And I am looking for an output which is like this.

```
A B C  OUT
1 . .  A
. . 1  C
1 1 . A,B
```

I wrote the program this way:

```
Data want;
set have; 
array U(3)A B C;
do i=1 to 3; 
if U(i)^=. then OUT=cat(vname(u(i),',');
end; 
run;
```

This gives only the last VNAME and not the concatenation.

Comment: Don't forget to include OUT in your `CAT` statement: `...then OUT=CAT(OUT,vname(u(i),',');`

Comment: @sasfrog Hi, now it gives blanks when i followed the way you wrote.

Comment: Sorry yep: catx - as per Keith's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a separator with concatenation, then `catx` is the function to use, or even better `call catx` which negates the need to put `out =` and using `out` in the concatenation as well.  Both these functions will trim any leading or trailing blanks.

The other problem with your code is that because `out` is derived from numeric variables, SAS will default the type to numeric as well.  You need to define the type to character beforehand (I've done this with a `length` statement.

The following code achieves your goal.

```
Data have;
input A B C; 
cards; 
1 . .
. . 1
1 1 .
run;

data want;
set have;
length out $20;
array U{3} A B C;
do i = 1 to 3;
if not missing(U{i}) then call catx(',',out,vname(U{i}));
end;
drop i;
run;
```